# iText how to add bookmarks to existing PDF linking to locations of extracted text

Tags: java, regex, pdf, itext

I am trying to use the `TextExtractionStrategy` and `PdfStamper setOutlines` classes of iText 5.5 to extract text from an existing PDF, search the extracted text of each page for matches to a pattern, and in one case if there is a match (to a paragraph number), I want a bookmark pointing to the page, named for the first matching paragraph number on the page.  In another case if there is a match to an independent claim number (a type of patent claim that does not relate back to a previous claim), I want a bookmark pointing to the page and named for the list of independent claims appearing on that page. Instead I am ending up with bookmarks repeating the names of previous bookmarks and/or pointing to the wrong pages.  This is really a compound question, but I think there must be others who want to do this same thing - essentially auto-generate predictive bookmark outlines for pdf's following a standard format, based on extracted text.

Here is my code with comments explaining where it did not do what I expected; I appreciate any suggestions:

```
if (ref.isUSReference()) {
        int  frontPageNum = pageNumbers[0];
        int drawingsPageNum = pageNumbers[1];
        int specPageNum = pageNumbers[2];
        int claimsPageNum = pageNumbers[3];
        int certificateOfCorrectionPageNum = pageNumbers[4];
        int reexaminationPageNum = pageNumbers[5];
```

`int[] pageNumbers is a set of section heading page numbers in the document fed into this method as an argument`

```
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    String[] textFromPages = new String[reader.getNumberOfPages()];
```

`In my case PdfReader reader is reading from the absolute path of a pdf document stored on my computer`

```
    String textFromPage;
    String lowerTextFromPage;


 Pattern paragraphNum = Pattern.compile("\\Q[\\E\\d{4}\\Q]\\E");
 Matcher paragraphNumMatcher;
 MatchResult paraNum;
 String paraNumber;

 Pattern indClaim = Pattern.compile("\\n(?!\\b1\\.)(\\d+)\\.[\\s\\n]{0,2}(An?\\b|In[\\s\\n]+an?\\b)(?!.{0,50}(?:according to|claim \\d))");
 Matcher indClaimMatcher;
 MatchResult iClaim;
 List<String> indClaimNums = new ArrayList<>();
 String indClaimsBookmarkTitle;
 String indClaimsBookmarkTitleClean;

 int oddColNum;
 int evenColNum;

        Comparator<String> compareNum = new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

                    return Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2));
                }
              };


       ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> outlines 
                 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
         HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         HashMap<String, Object> drawings = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
         HashMap<String, Object> drawingSheet = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
         HashMap<String, Object> specification = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
         HashMap<String, Object> specParagraph = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
         HashMap<String, Object> specColumnNum = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
         HashMap<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         HashMap<String, Object> additionalIndClaims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         HashMap<String, Object> certificateOfCorrection = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         HashMap<String, Object> reexaminationCertificate = new HashMap<String, Object>();


         outlines.add(map);
     //    String filename = pdfOut.getName();
         map.put("Title", pdf.getName());
         map.put ("Action", "GoTo");
         map.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", 1));
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> kids
                 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
         map.put ("Kids", kids);

         ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> drawingSheets
                 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> specParagraphs
                 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> specColumnNums
                 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> indClaims
                 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

      for (int n=1; n<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); n++) {
            textFromPages[n-1] = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, n, strategy); 
            textFromPage = new String();
            textFromPage = textFromPages[n-1];
            lowerTextFromPage = textFromPage.toLowerCase();

            indClaimMatcher = indClaim.matcher(textFromPage);

            if (n==drawingsPageNum) {
                kids.add(drawings);
                drawings.put("Title", "Drawings");
                drawings.put("Action", "GoTo");
                drawings.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", n));
            }
            if (drawingsPageNum != 0 && n>=drawingsPageNum && n<specPageNum) {
               drawingSheet = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
               drawings.put("Kids", drawingSheets);
               drawingSheets.add(drawingSheet);
               drawingSheet.put("Title", "Sheet " + (n-drawingsPageNum+1));
               drawingSheet.put("Action", "GoTo");
               drawingSheet.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", n));
            }
            if (n==specPageNum) {
                kids.add(specification);
                specification.put("Title", "Specification");
                specification.put("Action", "GoTo");
                specification.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", n));
                specification.put("Kids", specColumnNums);
                specification.put("Kids", specParagraphs);
            }
            if (ref.isUSUtility() && n>=specPageNum && n<claimsPageNum) {
                oddColNum = 2*(n-specPageNum)+1;
                evenColNum = 2*(n-specPageNum)+2;
                specColumnNum = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                specColumnNums.add(specColumnNum);
                specColumnNum.put("Title", "Cols. " + oddColNum + "-" + evenColNum);
                specColumnNum.put("Action", "GoTo");
                specColumnNum.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", n));               
            }
```

`Here is the first place I am having troubles - the expected output is a bookmark titled as the first paragraph (formatted as "[0001]", e.g.) of each page of the patent specification - instead in one case I got paragraph [0014] three times (the first pointing where it should and the second and third bookmarks pointing to subsequent pages), then paragraph [0056] six times, the second through sixth instances pointing to the five pages after where paragraph [0056] actually appeared, and then paragraph [0137] three times.  The document was the publicly available U.S. Patent Application Publication No. 2013/0123456 in case anyone wants to try to recreate my test case`

```
           if (ref.isUSAppPublication() && n>=specPageNum && n<claimsPageNum) {

                paragraphNumMatcher = paragraphNum.matcher(textFromPages[n-1]);
                if (paragraphNumMatcher.find()) {

                paraNum = paragraphNumMatcher.toMatchResult();
                paraNumber = paraNum.group(0);
                specParagraph = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                specParagraph.put("Title", paraNumber);
                specParagraph.put("Action", "GoTo");
                specParagraph.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", n));
                specParagraphs.add(specParagraph);
                }

            }
            if (n==claimsPageNum) {
                kids.add(claims);
                claims.put("Title", "Claims");
                claims.put("Action", "GoTo");
                claims.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", n));
                claims.put("Kids", indClaims);
            }
```

`Here is the second place I am having troubles - In the case of US Pat. App. Pub. No. 2013/0123456 I expected one bookmark to "Additional independent claim(s): 3" and another bookmark to "Additional independent claim(s): 16."*  Instead there were bookmarks "Additional independent claim(s): 3" (pointing to the page of claim 3 where I expected); "Additional independent claim(s): 3, 16" (pointing to the page of claim 16), and "Additional independent claims: 16" (pointing to the page after claim 16).  In some cases I expect a comma-separated list, i.e., where the independent claim numbers appear on the same page, but here they do not. (*Technically speaking, in fact only claim 3 is an independent claim, but my regular expression is matching a false positive on claim 16; however, that is not important to my question here).`

```
            if (n>=claimsPageNum) {
                indClaimNums.clear();
                while (indClaimMatcher.find()) {
                    iClaim = indClaimMatcher.toMatchResult();
                    indClaimNums.add(iClaim.group(1));
                   }
                if (indClaimNums.size() > 0) {
                    indClaimNums.sort(compareNum);
                    indClaimsBookmarkTitle =  "Additional Independent Claim(s): " + indClaimNums;
                    indClaimsBookmarkTitleClean = indClaimsBookmarkTitle.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                    additionalIndClaims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    additionalIndClaims.put("Title", indClaimsBookmarkTitleClean);
                    additionalIndClaims.put("Action","GoTo");
                    additionalIndClaims.put("Page", String.format("%d", n));
                    indClaims.add(additionalIndClaims);
                   }

               }  
            if (n==certificateOfCorrectionPageNum) {
                kids.add(certificateOfCorrection);
                certificateOfCorrection.put("Title", "Certificate of Correction");
                certificateOfCorrection.put("Action", "GoTo");
                certificateOfCorrection.put("Page", String.format("%d", n));
               } 
            if (n==reexaminationPageNum) {
                kids.add(reexaminationCertificate);
                reexaminationCertificate.put("Title", "Reexamination Certificate");
                reexaminationCertificate.put("Action", "GoTo");
                reexaminationCertificate.put("Page", String.format("%d", n));
            }    


    }      
    stamper.setOutlines(outlines);
       }
           stamper.close(); 
           reader.close();

       }
     catch (DocumentException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```